# Smartface 4.3.0. IOS Emulator Error

Tags: ios, emulation, smartface.io

Smartface emulator works on android but for ios it gives me "Keep calm ;) 
You need to download Smartface in action from app store and then please try again.
" error. But I already installed it.

My itunes version is 12.1.2.
I checked firewall it does not block idb.
I restarted my iphone and my computer twice.
My cable is original.
Allowed my IOS device.

What can be the problem?

Comment: I too am facing the same issue with my iPhone 5s (iOS 8.3) and iTunes 12.1.2. It seems like Apple has beefed up its security in ios 8.3 (http://www.macrumors.com/2015/04/13/ios-8-3-ifunbox-itools-sandbox-app-access/) and Smartface might be impacted due to this.

Answer (score 1):

If you search the web you can see that, with the 8.3 update there were some unexpected changes which effect the connection between device and the computer.
This will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if idb.exe or idb2.exe is running or background if yes please kill the process and try it again.

Comment: I cannot see any process named idb or idb2 ??

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround that I figured out. [Download this file](http://www.mediafire.com/download/i2243i5fr0qg46m/iTunesMobileDevice.dll) and replace with the existed one in this location : `C:\Program Files (x86)\Smartface\Smartface App Studio 4.3\Utilities\iOS`

It caused because of latest iTunes update. Some API's has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

My Itunes Version is 12.2.27 - Smartface-In-Action Application lasest version is already installed - im using original cable - i changed iTunesMobileDevice.dll - idb or idb2 not working at the background but still smartface emulator not working..

Searching for devices...
Device found: xxxxxxx

Keep calm ;) 
You need to download Smartface in action from app store and then please try again.