# How to connect iPhone 5s to SmartFace?

Tags: ios, iphone, smartface.io

I've just installed smartface version 4.3.0

I connected my iPhone 5S to the laptop using USB cable.

I launched Smartface App Studio, clicked on Device Emulator from toolbar.
Clicked on Yes button when User Account dialog appears.
Progress Dialog appears, it says:
"Searchign for devices...
Devices found: Simon's iPhone

Keep calm ;)
You need to download Smartface in action from app store and then please try again.

Same issue again? Please refer to Troubleshooting document!"

I downloaded the app on my iPhone and launched, what haven't I done?

Comment: This is not at all about writing software.

Comment: I cannot begin to write the software unless I can get the tools functioning!

Answer (score 1):

If your iOS version is 8.3, there were some unexpected changes with 8.3 update and it effects the connection between device and the computer.
This will be fixed soon.

Comment: I did have other issues after the 8.3 update, also lost all bluetooth connectivity.  After searching online, found solution was to reset network settings, bluetooth now works again.

Comment: Trying with earlier release of ITunes will fix your problems. Latest Itunes changed its dlls itself.

Comment: Any idea which version to downgrade too?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround that may be helpful to solve your problem, take a look here

[Smartface 4.3.0. IOS Emulator Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635725/smartface-4-3-0-ios-emulator-error/29891885#29891885)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution in your link, now I get:

```
Searching for devices...
Device found: iPhone

Keep calm ;) 
You need to download Smartface in action from app store and then please try again.

Same issue again? Please refer to Troubleshooting document!
```

I have smartface installed on my iphone already.